# Check for duplicate data among 250 blob files which are in azure storage container

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account

I have around 250 files in my azure storage account container. I need to compare and check all those files to see if there is any duplicate data. The files have list of json objects. Duplicate meaning identical json objects across any of these files. The total files size is around 60GB.

Could you please suggest a way to compare, check and identify if there are any duplicate data.

Please suggest if there is any tool available which can help me achieve this.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide details about what you mean by duplicate data.

Comment: Updated the question to explain about duplicate data

Answer (score 0):

Comparing 250+ files line by line, is an exhaustive task.

One solution that comes to mind is to use Hashing.

1. Create a Hash list.
2. Create a Dictionay, where Key is FileName and value is a hash.
3. For each file
4. Get the hash equivalent
5. Add the hash equivalent to the Hash list
6. Add a tuple to the dictionary, with Filename and the Hash string.

A hash-List do not entertain duplicate value. So the end result will be a unique list of Hash. To map back the hash items to the file-names, the dictionary will be helpful.